# Photon Multiplayer collision/trigger detection on Other Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer, photon

I am working on my Final Year Project, which is a chase tag Multiplayer game developed using Photon (PUN-2). The game involves two players in a room, where one player starts with the tag "chaser" and the other as the "runner". The objective is for the chaser to catch the runner within a 40-second time limit. If the chaser successfully catches the runner, they earn a point. On the other hand, if the runner manages to avoid being caught, they earn a point. After each round, the roles and tags switch, and the game continues for a total of 7 rounds. The player with the most points at the end wins.

I have already implemented the multiplayer functionality, scoreboard, and timer, but I need assistance with round switching and score counting. I'm not sure if I've provided enough information for you to understand my project. If you would like to offer assistance, please reach out to me on **Discord Hamad#7980**.

To implement the round switching and score counting the steps are:

1. Initialize the game with the chaser and runner roles assigned to the players.
2. Start the 40-second timer.
3. Monitor for collisions between the chaser and the runner.
4. If a collision occurs within the time limit, award a point to the chaser.
5. If the runner manages to avoid being caught within the time limit, award a point to the runner.
6. Update the scores for both players accordingly.
7. Check if 7 rounds have been completed. If not, proceed to the next round.
8. Switch the roles of the chaser and the runner for the next round.
9. Repeat steps 2-8 until all 7 rounds are complete.
10. Determine the winner based on the total points earned by each player.

Note: I Don't know how to detect collision/Trigger of other player on PHOTON.

PlayerManager.cs

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using System.IO;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotonView PV;
    public float rand;
    public int pl = 1;
    GameObject player;
    //GameObject controller;
    //GameObject Chaser, Enemy;
    void Awake()
    {
        PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rand = Random.Range(-2f, 2f);
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            CreateController();
        }
    void CreateController()
    {
        if (PV.ViewID == 1001 || PV.ViewID == 1002 || PV.ViewID == 1003) // player 1 is the chaser
        {
            Transform spawnpoint = Spawnmanager.instance.GetSpawnpoint();
            player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "CharacterController"), spawnpoint.position, spawnpoint.rotation, 0, new object[] {PV.ViewID});
           
        }
        else
        {
            Transform spawnpoint = Spawnmanager.instance.GetSpawnpoint();
            player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "CharacterController2"), spawnpoint.position, spawnpoint.rotation, 0, new object[] { PV.ViewID });
        }
    }
}
```

In PlayerController.cs where i detect the trigger,

```csharp
    void Start()
    {
        Chaser = GameObject.FindWithTag("Chaser");
        Enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy");
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name.Equals("Enemy"))
        {
            Runner.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;
            Chaser.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;

            if (Enemy.tag == "Runner")
            {
                Enemy.tag = "Chaser";
            }
            else
            {
                ScoreChaser++;
                Enemy.tag = "Runner";
            }
            if (Chaser.tag == "Runner")
            {
                Chaser.tag = "Chaser";
            }
            else
            {
                ScoreEnemy++;
                Chaser.tag = "Runner";
            }
            
            Debug.Log("ScoreChaser: " + ScoreChaser);

            //Chaser.transform.position = new Vector3(398.63f, -0.01f, 771f);
        } 
    }
```

This is not the whole script just the part where i try to switch rounds.

I gave tags manually to the prefabs of both players in my project. Also I wrote script which detects the collision. But it didn't go as expected. In game they are not switching their tags and also collision is not being detected.